# Automate a stored preocedure in sql 2012

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an aplication in vb.net that received an .csv field from an email and rename it like data.csv for example.
I have a stored procedure that load data from .csv field in a sql table. 
How can run automate this stored procedure when received data from aplication(the time when received data from aplication is not a specified time)?
I try to do this with a job from sql but there i can run that procedure at a specified time only and i don't wan't this.

Comment: Why can't the application invoke the procedure after it renamed the file?

Answer (score 1):

Why not call the procedure from the app?
The workflow would be:

1. App receives and email
2. csv attachment is extracted from email and renamed
3. App calls database procedure which imports data from file to table

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows OS you can create a service, Which can trigger automatically when the file receives to a particular folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have an option to modify that VB.NET application, you may invoke the stored procedure right after the file is received.
2. Otherwise you may write a windows service that could raise an event as soon as the file is received in particular folder.

See
[Introduction to Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx)
[FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)